# change variable values based on preceding value

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(subject = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), 
             time = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), 
             performance = c(1,0,-1,-1,0,1,1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,-1,0,1,1,-1,0,0,1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,-1,0,-1,-1,0))
```

What I would like to do is to change some of the entries in the performance variable. More specifically, if a "-1" entry is preceded by a "1", I want to change the "-1" to "0".

However, this should be done within subjects only, but not across subjects (all of the subjects have a varying number of sessions).

So, this is what I'd like to have in the end:

```
 df2 =data.frame(subject = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), 
                        time = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), 
                        performance = c(1,0,-1,-1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,-1,0,-1,-1,0))
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance!
S.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`,

```
df %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(performance = replace(performance, which(performance + lag(performance)==0 & performance == -1), 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data.table approach, where I first create a `flag` column which is then used to subset the data and update the `performance` column by reference.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df) # or setDT(df)
dt[, flag := performance == -1 & shift(performance, 1L) == 1, by = subject]
dt[(flag), performance := 0][, flag := NULL]
```

I chose to do it with an intermediate flag-column because I expect that to perform very well for large data sets. If performance is not your concern, you could of course use `ifelse` or `replace` instead.

Comment: Do you also get 0 for value 29?

Comment: Right, 29 should be a 0 - sorry for that! And thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, but should work:

```
dftest <- df
for (i in 2:nrow(dftest)) {
  if(
    dftest$performance[i] == -1 && dftest$performance[i - 1] == 1
  ){
    if(
      dftest$subject[i] == dftest$subject[i - 1]
    ) {
      dftest$performance[i] <- 0
    }
 }
}

all.equal(df2, dftest) # ONE ERROR
```

This gives an error in line 29 - can you check whether your example df2 is correct here? If I understand the question correctly `df2$performance[29]` should be `0`?

Comment: I believe this is the most appropriate when `df$subject` is ordered. Note that, in R, you can avoid the loop since all relational operations operate on "vector"s. I.e. the above translates to the more efficient `df$performance[c(FALSE, df$subject[-1] == df$subject[-nrow(df)]) & c(FALSE, (df$performance[-nrow(df)] == 1L) & (df$performance[-1] == -1L))] = 0`

Comment: Yep, didn't think about the unordered case. As for the loop - yeah, I personally like the dplyr solution most, I'm just kinda used to using loops...

Comment: Right, line 29 should be a 0! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution using `by` and `sapply`:

```
gr <- do.call(c, by(df, df$subject, function(x) {
c(FALSE, unlist(sapply(1:length(x$performance), 
function(y) (x$performance[y] == -1) & (x$performance[y-1] == 1))))
}))
df[gr, 3] <- 0
cbind(df, df2)
```